# How do I take an indefinitely large set of user inputs and save them into an array?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am making a program (in school for intro to computer programming(dont worry, this is all extra credit stuff, not asking for cheat answers)) that will take a user decided set of user inputs and save them all to do math (more specifically, finding the median, but I want to figure that out myself) on them. I am fairly sure that I need an array to do this (even my teacher hinted that that is what you needed to do).

My plan is to have a variable x that will decide the amount of separate numbers in the array (will not only be the number in the array, but also the number to check how many times I want to run the loop for asking for numbers), and then to have that many user inputted numbers inputting by the user, and then to be able to take those numbers and find the median of them (I will probably have to check if the number is even or odd first, then sort the numbers (somehow), then find the middlemost number.)

Thanks!

Comment: Regardless whether this is homework or not, we're not here to write code for you.

Comment: Like I said, I wanted to figure out the median stuff myself. I just want to know how to accept n amount of user inputs in an array so I can do math with the numbers individually.

Comment: The community here is not going to respond well if you have not attempted to code at least a few lines.

Comment: It sounds like you have a plan. Start implementing it!

Comment: David I have definitely been trying, messing with arrays for about an hour (Mateuszlewko says that I probably shouldnt even be using an array anyways though)

Comment: @Koopi You would have gotten a lot better response if you have posted the code you have been messing with regardless of the state of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using array which has fixed size, try using [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).
List allows you to add indefinitely many (until it fits into memory) elements.
So, in your for loop you could read user input and add it to the list.
After that you can sort entire list using `sort` method and return middle element, which is a median.

It could look like that:

```
int n = //TODO: read number of user inputs
List<int> elems = new List<int> ();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int x = // get input
    elems.Add(x);
}

Console.WriteLine(elems[elems.Length / 2]);
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try that!

Comment: @Koopi if you find it useful you can mark as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the `List<T>` class [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) for storing the numbers.

For reading input, see [Console.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx).

For converting `string` to `int`, take a look at [int.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx).

I gave you the tools, now start coding! :D

Comment: yes sir! I will!